# why is this array coming up as void,

Tags: objective-c

ive logged the key and sorted keys and they both exist, is this method for inserting objects not usable?

```
    
    [self.list removeAllObjects];
    NSArray *sortedKeys = @[];

    sortedKeys = [[AQRManager sharedInstance].notificationRequests allKeys];

        for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
            NSInteger count = [[AQRManager sharedInstance] countForBundleIdentifier:key];
            if (count == 0) continue;
            [self.list addObject: @{
                @"bundleIdentifier": key,
                @"notificationCount": @(count)
            }];
            NSLog(@"AQUArius %@",self.list);
        }
```

Comment: It seems ok，Where is the problem？

Comment: the list is empty when it is logged, thank you for responding btw

Comment: it isn't empty it is just null the output is ```aquarius - (null)```

Comment: the list shouldn't be null, make sure the list exists before the add operation? make sure the list is correctly created and won't be release by autorelease?